# Getting tablenames from sys.tables and using them to find max value of a column in each table

Tags: sql-server

I've transaction Backup tables in sqlserver and all have a similar naming convention like `RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG_[MONYYYY].`I've queried `sys.tables` to find out 82 backup tables

I now need the max and min of the date  in the table,so that i can check if any data's missing.

I need the output to be like

```
Table_name,MAX(DATE_TIME),MIN(DATE_TIME)
```

Is there a way I can reference all the tables from `sys.tables` and use them in from part of the main query.

Comment: `sp_MSforeachtable` is an undocumented stored procedure but you'll find plenty of posts, answers, etc online showing how you can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sp_MSForeachtable` you can filter the tables using the `@Whereand` parameter to restrict it to only the tables beginning with "RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG_":

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable  
    @command1 = 'select ''?'', MAX(DATE_TIME),MIN(DATE_TIME) from ?', 
    @Whereand = ' and o.name like ''RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG_%'''
```

***EDIT***
To make this even easier to use, you can insert into a temp table and then select from this:

```
CREATE TABLE #result
(
    TableName SysName,
    MaxDateTime DateTime,
    MinDateTime DateTime
)

exec sp_MSforeachtable  
    @command1 = 'INSERT INTO #result select ''?'', MAX(DATE_TIME), MIN(DATE_TIME) from ?', 
    @Whereand = ' and o.name like  ''RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG_%''',
    @postcommand = 'select * from #result;drop table #result'
```

Comment: Awesome. I recommended this in my edited complete answer below, I've definitely neglected the use of this clearly useful procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL like that. You may have to tweak it as you didn't give the exact schema of your tables:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'create table #temp(Table_Name nvarchar(max), MaxDate datetime, MinDate datetime); '

select @sql = @sql + 'insert into #temp select ''' + name + ''', MAX(DATE_TIME),MIN(DATE_TIME) from [' + name + ']; ' 
from sys.tables where type = 'U' and name like 'RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG%'

set @sql = @sql + ' select * from #temp; drop table #temp;'

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever: Unbelievable. I didn't know sp_msforeachtable had such potential. I've always made these pages long scripts with while loops and a lot of dynamic SQL.

So OP, as an answer, you might try something like this for instance:

**EDIT**

You can also get the set out by using a temporary table to store the results, such as:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP (TableName VARCHAR(256) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, MaxDate DATETIME, MinDate DATETIME)

EXEC SP_msForeachTable 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') IN 
(SELECT T.object_id
FROM sys.tables T
JOIN sys.columns C on C.object_id = T.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas S on S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE T.name like ''RECEIVER_CHARGE_LOG_%'' AND C.name LIKE ''DATE_TIME'' 
AND S.name = ''dbo'')
   EXEC(''INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT ''''?'''' Table_Name, MAX(DATE_TIME) MaxDate, MIN(DATE_TIME) MinDate FROM ?'')'

SELECT * 
FROM #TEMP 
ORDER BY MinDate
```

Though I recommend you use Steve Ford's template for the sp_msForEachTable procedure, since it's far more reasonable and efficient.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an insert into a temp table so that you only get one results set out with all table details.